# How do I change characters on The Binding of Isaac?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

I already feel like a complete idiot for asking this, but I just can't figure it out. Could anybody tell me what key I need to use to exit a menu? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can pick your character whenever you start a new game (except for any challenge). It's a roguelike so you're expected to either complete the game or die trying and then start over.

Answer (score 0):

You can select them before starting a run. That being said most characters will need some actions to be completed in order to unlock them.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).